# Connect to ldap through coldfusion

Tags: php, windows, ssl, coldfusion, ldap

I am trying to connect to LDAP server using below Coldfusion code. But I get an error "Authentication failed:[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903C9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v23f0 ]"

```
<cfldap  
    action = "Query" 
    server = "xxxx.edu" 
    attributes = "*" 
    name = "result" 
    password = "yyy" 
    port = "000" 
    start = "cn=xxx,ou=xxx,dc=xx,dc=xx,dc=edu" 
    username = "xxx">
```

Are the parameters used in the above cfldap tag are correct or do I need to add any other parameters? Does this issue relate to SSL certificate? Any idea what should I use in "start"?

I have successfully connected to LDAP using php using the same parameter values
but the same values when used are throwing an error in Coldfusion? Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I suggest that right-now would be a very good time to contact the security folks in your company and ask them what *they* see on the LDAP logs. Have they made proper arrangements for *this* application to connect? Here's a URL that I found with DuckDuckGo search (on a Microsoft site) where, at least, they say they **[SOLVED]** it ... https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2786da89-3dc7-43d9-8a75-3db54825ff36/solved-ldap-authentication-error-code-49-80090308-comment-acceptsecuritycontext-error-data?forum=winserverDS

Comment: Another interesting-looking link on DevShed, *(which might be more useful to you ...)* is:  http://forums.devshed.com/ldap-programming-76/javax-naming-authenticationexception-ldap-error-code-49-80090308-ldaperr-dsid-121363.html.  A seemingly directly-relevant comment there said: *"Error code 49 is the equivalent of bad credentials at login. If you are trying to connect to AD the best method is to bind using sAMAccountName@corp.XXX.com as the user instead of the standard full DN."*